# Vaadin Table: no components in table

Tags: java, vaadin

In my table I render rows contains components. After loading data source to table sometimes there are empty fields (components aren't visible, text - yes). I have not any exceptions.

This happens when I scrolling table content. After refreshing table data source everything is ok.

What's wrong?
In attachement there is an example.

[image]

Comment: What container datasource are you using? Perhaps some duplicate primary identifier? (Duplicate itemId's)

Comment: Which Vaadin version do you use?

Comment: I use Vaadin 7.3.10, container:  BeanItemContainer. I mapping database entity to my own bean which contains setters and getters for TextField, ComboBox, etc. Db entity has hashcode and equals methods by Id but my own bean not. Table is an addon: FilteringTable (https://vaadin.com/directory#addon/filteringtable). Maybe it is good answer that entries have duplicate primary identifiers, I check it. But when I setup that same data source and load it to the table second time everything is fine. All entries in my DB are unique

Comment: I would try to use the most latest Vaadin version which is 7.4.1. Might be this issue which is fixed in 7.4.1: http://dev.vaadin.com/ticket/16611

Answer (score 0):

I found solution. I think so that might be an bug.

INVALID SOLUTION:

1. Load data to table
2. Scroll table with data to eg. 50% of table content
3. Load new data to table
4. Table doesn't display all components

CORRECT SOLUTION:

1. Load data to table
2. Scroll table with data to eg. 50% of table content
3. **Scroll table to top, to the first table item**
4. Load new data to table
5. **Table display all components**

In Vaadin 7.4.1 there is that same bug. Maybe recreating table should help?

OK. Now it works. This is temporary solution. I re-create table and load data to new table:

```
private void createTable() {
    pzbs = (FilterTable) buildTable();
    h.addComponent(pzbs);
    h.setExpandRatio(pzbs, 1.0f);
}

private void recreateTable() {
    h.removeComponent(pzbs);
    createTable();
}

private Component buildRoutes() {
    routes = new ListSelect() {
        {
            setNullSelectionAllowed(false);
            setSizeUndefined();
            setWidth(100.0f, Sizeable.Unit.PERCENTAGE);
            setHeight(100.0f, Sizeable.Unit.PERCENTAGE);
            setImmediate(true);
        }
    };
    routes.addValueChangeListener((Property.ValueChangeEvent event) -> {
        if (routes.getValue() != null) {
            recreateTable();
            countAndUpdatePercentage(countCorrectReadouts());
            sendedToPSG.select(null);
            selectedRoute = (KTREntity) routes.getValue();
            updateTable();
        }
    });

    return routes;
}
```